# devc++ autocomplete stops working after writing few lines of code

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, dev-c++

I am a beginner in coding and I am recommended to start with c++ as my first programming language so I am using devc++ as my first ide. the auto complete feature stops working after writing 2-3 lines of code. Similar thing happens when i use codeblocks. Please help .

Comment: try VisualStudio, it's a very easy IDE for beginners, and it has industrial strength. It's also free now for non commercial use. However, anybody suggesting C++ to a beginner as starting language is probably raving mad. Just try python or maybe Java for beginners these are much more user friendly.

Comment: I have also tried vs code using c/c++ MS and code runner extensions but debug and run feature is not working